# Soundcloud API, is there a way to restrict the search to match exact phrase?

Tags: soundcloud

I noticed that when I query the API sometime I get results that are not really close to what I searched for.

Is there a method to get zero results and prevent false results?

I would like the search for "Babyface" and DO NOT get "baby smile" etc...

Answer (score 0):

From SoundCloud:

> Most endpoints will accept a q param which you can use to specify a keyword to search for in fields like title, username, description, etc. depending on the resource type.

So, not much detail there but they probably return results by relevance. I don't see anything about exact keyword searches.

What you can do is check the query results and make sure your search param actually exists in the track title, username, description, etc.